# what happens when you don't pass 'self' while declaring a method inside a inherited class

Tags: python, oop

I have the following code in python2. I wanted to know if inheritance works or basic class works if we don't pass 'self' or don't have an init method in the class.

here is the code

```
 class Animal:
   def whoAmi():
   print "Animal"

  >>> class Dog(Animal):
      pass
     ...
  >>> d= Dog()
  >>> d.whoAmi
  <bound method Dog.whoAmi of <__main__.Dog instance at 0x0000000004ED3348>>
  >>> d.whoAmi()
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  TypeError: whoAmi() takes no arguments (1 given)
  >>> d.whoAmi
  <bound method Dog.whoAmi of <__main__.Dog instance at 0x0000000004ED3348>>
```

why doesn't it print "Animal" here?

Comment: `whoAmi() takes no arguments (1 given)` you declare a function without `self` as parameter, so no parameters for your function. But when class instance calls the function, it passes `self` automatically. Thats why `takes no arguments (1 given)`

Answer (score 2):

Lets first tackle why doesn't it print "Animal".

The clue is is in the error message:

> TypeError: whoAmi() takes no arguments (**1 given**)

When you do `d.whoAmi()`, really what Python is doing is `Dog.whoAmi(d)`. Since your method does not take any arguments, you get that exception.

By convention (as is it case with many style "rules" in Python), for those methods of classes that work on instances, the first argument is called *`self`*. However, it can be called anything you want. The key thing to remember is that there **must be at least one argument**. You can name it whatever you want, but the agreement in the Python community is to call it `self`.

Here is an example showing that it really doesn't matter what you call it:

```
>>> class Foo():
...   def whoami(blah):
...      print "Boo"
...
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.whoami()
Boo
```

Inheritance works fine even if you don't have methods with `self`, as it is perfectly normal to have class-level methods in Python.

All methods that have double underscores (sometimes called "dunder" methods), like `__init__` are optional. You don't have to define them if the default functionality works for you.

The key thing to remember here is that the argument to `self` is passed implicitly by Python. You don't really "pass" `self`. Python knows that the method is being called on an instance, and passes the instance as the first argument to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you’re are effectively initiating Dog, you’re creating a `self`. So, when you write `d.whoAmi()`, the interpreter inserts `self` as a function argument.

If you tried:

```
d = Dog
d.whoAmi()
```

It should work as expected. 
By the way, you should put the decorator `@staticmethod` in he top of your `whoAmi` function for it to work the way you did.